# A matrix equation $Ax=0$ has infinite solutions, does $A^Tx = 0$ have infinite solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transpose

I'm wondering whether a system with a transpose of a matrix has the same type of solution that the original matrix system has. If an equation $Ax=0$ equation has a unique solution, would a system with $A$ transpose instead of $A$ also have a unique solution? And what about with no solution, and infinite solutions?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What is a solution of a matrix?

Comment: Some clarification would be good here. What do you mean by a matrix having unique/infinite/no solutions? Are you talking about a matrix equation like $Ax = b$? Because then it depends on both $A$ and $b$ (there could be infinitely many solutions for some $b$, and no solution for others) and it's not clear what you mean by its transpose. Are you talking about homogenous equations $Ax = 0$? Because then there's always at least one solution in that case. Also, are you interested in non-square matrices here?

Comment: fixed my dumbass question. Sorry MSE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are dealing with square matrices, then the answer is yes. You are essentially asking if the matrix is invertible or not, and $A$ is invertible iff $\det(A)\ne0$ and $\det(A)=\det\!\left(A^T\right)$.

However,
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
3&1&2\\
2&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\-2
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and any real multiple of this solution is a solution. Yet
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
3&2\\
1&0\\
2&1
\end{bmatrix}
x
=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
requires $x=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}$.